# Conexão em PHP via ODBC ao banco CACHE da intersystems

Tags: php, cache, odbc

Bom dia pessoal.
Alguém tem experiência de como fazer uma conexão via odbc com o banco caché da intersystems no PHP?
Já instalei no meu host o driver ODBC e conectou certo com o banco, porem estou com dificuldades em iniciar a conexão.php.

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui conectar, fazer uma consulta e imprimir os dados conforme abaixo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang='pt-BR'>
        <head>
            <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' integrity='sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6' crossorigin='anonymous'>
        </head>
        <body>
<title>Teste</title>
 <head>
 <body>
 <?php
    $usu='DB_USER';
    $senha='DB_PASSWORD';
    $connect = odbc_connect('DSN_NAME',$usu,$senha);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM banco";
    $result = odbc_exec($connect , $sql);
      ?>
<div class='container container-sm'><br>
<table class='table table-hover table-sm'>
 <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Conta</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>nome</th>
 </tr>

 <?php
  while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) {

    echo 
        '<tr>
            <td>'.odbc_result($result, 1).'<td/> 
            <td>'.odbc_result($result, 2).'<td/> 
            <td>'.odbc_result($result, 3).'<td/>
        </tr>';
  }
 odbc_close($connect);
 ?>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

´´´
```